# library not found for -lRNGestureHandler

Tags: xcode, react-native

When I try to run react-native run-ios it's throwing the following error.

```
d: library not found for -lRNGestureHandler
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

can anyone please help me out on this?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue but i believe that this isn't related specifically to RNGestureHandler but to the way your paths are set in your xcode project and your `podfile` configuration.  At least that's what it was for me.

In your `build settings` search for `header search paths` and `library search paths`. I removed the current paths and set the new paths to `$(inherited)` for both `header search paths` and `library search paths` to both `debug` and `release`.

You need to do it for all your `targets`.  In my case, i did it for `myApp` and `myAppTest`

One more thing i did because cocoapods threw a message telling me to do so.. is to to search for `other linker flags` in `linking` and add `$(inherited) -ObjC -lc++` to both `debug` and `release` under `other linker flags`.

Do it for `all` your `targets` like i mentioned above.  I hope this helps you or helps someone else.  I did for me for ios.